# Visual search on TeX.SE

Tags: discussion, support, images, search

In many questions we're likely to post an image of what we're looking for.  And there are often multiple visuals for the answer. Is there a way to search the questions via the thumbnails posted on the thread?
A more visual approach like in 
[Texample](http://www.texample.net/).

Comment: moving the question to meta.tex.stackexchange.com is much better.

Comment: Understood merci !

Comment: its on topic on the meta site (but it can be moved there automatically, the site doesn't have any thing but you could try google image search or similar however I suspect that can not pick out layout and font issues shown in typical images here

Comment: @OnlyTheParanoidSurvive that can be done automatically if you vote for that above.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  I actuallyproceed that way. I go on Google search first then I am redirected to tex SE which did not seem efficient to me :/

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb oddly enough google is better at searching than stackexchange, and stackexchange is better at collating answers, so a split site approach isn't that unnatural.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Oh thank you for informing that. I am relatively new to this site.

Comment: You can do a google image search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com <search term>`. This turns out to be rather efficient.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One thing one can do is to perform a Google image search for

```
site:tex.stackexchange.com <search term(s)>
```

I am using this sometimes to find possible duplicates, and, according to my experience, this turns out to work surprisingly well.

Actually, I sometimes wish that users asking questions could do that search themselves. If they end up not precisely finding what they are looking for, they have still a starting point and "references".

It seems to be true, though, that this search works best if you have already a solution to the problem in mind because then you can add the relevant key words to the search terms.

Comment: Totally agreed. And on top of that I sometimes find ideas in other threads whereas the question asked was not of my interest (a priori).

Answer (score 7):

There doesn't exist a native way of doing that on the network. However, as already mentioned in [Schrödinger's cat's answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8522/5764), you can use the [image search option with Google](https://www.google.ca/imghp), targeting this site via

```
site:tex.stackexchange.com
```

Note though that this may only be valuable in select instances where posters did use images. Some threads only post an image in the question, but the correct answers may have been simple enough to not post an image. Also, if you're looking for a specific issue, it's often better described in the post (with words) than in an image; the image might have been added, but without any visual indication of the issue.

In short, I doubt you'll find what you're looking for using a visual search, because the Q&A environment is not set up in that way.